# This question was closed on both hardware sites?

Tags: support, asking-questions, close-reasons

I am really confused why.... this happened.

There, the information for the close of the question on  hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com was:

> Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on Super User.

And the information given on superuser was:

> Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs.

Help me with this... I am confused about what is happening here...

Comment: If we still had *too localized*  as close reason, that one would apply here. You don't describe a generalized problem that applies to a wide audience, your are asking for consulting on your specific case and the answers are at best entertaining for you but not for many others. Either ask for an hardware device that can sustain a strict specified workload, that can be asked on hw.se. Or "invent" a problem with your setup that you need a solution for, as that can be asked on SU. Asking us to decide for you are not a great fit for the Q/A model.

Comment: Can you screenshot https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14494 for us and share that as well?

Comment: I think you need to ask on Super User meta. It is clear to me that you ask about a usage scenario for drives you already have. HWrec.se is for finding hardware that conforms to specific specs, so the closure on HWrecs.se is correct. I'm not convinced closing on SU is correct but I'm not enough of a regular there to fully grasp why that question isn't suitable. That is something only their per-site meta regulars can explain to you.

Comment: Moved over to MSU - since the HR.SE question is fairly clear cut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well - I might have closed for different reasons (too localised sounds awesome but we don't have it anymore, and to some extent its missed, and I might consider it opinion based).

I guess the core problem is the question is phrased as a "should I choose A or B".

While *generally* editing the question *after* the answers are posted is frowned upon - but lets consider your real issue. That you have 2 drives of roughly equal size is irrelevant.

Its possible to look at this question 2 ways, depending on how generic you want to be

What really concerns you is

1. You have a high performance drive in a high wear/usage situation, and you want to know if it would adversely affect its overall lifespan.

That SSDs are not fragile things is fairly well documented on SU - I have [an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/990710/how-damaged-is-my-ssd-disc/990715#990715) or two of my own (that need refreshing! One of my sources is dead)

There's a *risk* of dupe closure but your current answers are a frame challenge to "will this kill my SSD" - rescope for that, and at worst, include the HDD as an option *you* are considering as an alternative.

2. Picking the *right* sort of storage for your application.

In the SU perspective, you *could* very craftily get away with looking at attributes the drive would need, though since you already have a drive, it wouldn't work

From a Hardware Recs perspective, you could ask a question about picking a *new* drive with your performance, cost and longevity requirements

3. Monitoring drive health on linux

Since you don't have the same suite samsung provides on linux,

Its also worth remembering drives die for reasons *other* than cell deterioration, wear related failures are often gradual or graceful, and people have been abusing consumer SSDs for things like this a while.